# How to make children div with 100% height and width?

Tags: html, css

how to make children div with 100% height and width?

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
     Here 100% height and width child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
     Here 100% height and width child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can post your CSS here so we can see what you've tried so far?

Comment: Could you also explain your question a little more? I'm unclear what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I would like to have two sections that would be child 1 and child 2. When showing section 1 (child 1) the contents of that div would appear fullscreen (100% height and width). Rolling the site down going to section 2 (child 2) content would also be on fullscreen, like spotify website https://www.spotify.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each child to appear fullscreen, meaning 100% height and width of the browser viewport, then add `100vh;` to the divs you want to affect. The caveat is that this has support back to IE 11 only for IE browsers.

```
.child1,
.child2 {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

They will be 100% width already since they are `div` elements which block level elements.

```css
.child1,
.child2 {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
     Here 100% height and width child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
     Here 100% height and width child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp) out.

CSS Height and Width.

You can set your css file like this.

This element has a height of 200 pixels and a width of 50%

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This element has a height of 100 pixels and a width of 500 pixels.

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}
```